# How to show that the limit of a multivariable function exists using $\epsilon -\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $\dfrac{x+4y}{1-x+y} \to 3 $ as $(x,y) \to (1,-1) $

I have no problem bounding the numerator. But I got stucked at the denominator. I have no idea what expression to bound it. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: If you can do an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof for tjhe limit of $1/w$ as $w \to 1$ then you should be able to modify the argument to deal with the denominator near $1 -1 -1 = -1$. That and the product of limits will finish the job.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$|\dfrac{x+4y}{1-x+y} - 3|=  \frac {|4(x-1)+(y+1)|}{|1-x+y|}$$

If $\delta$ is small enough, we have $$|4(x-1)+(y+1)|\le |4(x-1)|+|(y+1)|<\frac {\epsilon}{2}$$

On the other hand if   $\delta< 1/4 $ we have $$|1-x+y|>1/2$$ whenever $|x-1|<\delta $ and $|y+1|<\delta $

Thus if $\delta$ is small enough we have  $$ \frac {|4(x-1)+(y+1)|}{|1-x+y|}<\epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\biggl|\,\frac{x+4y}{1-x+y}-3\,\biggr|=\biggl|\,\frac{4x+y-3}{1-x+y}\,\biggr|.$$
Now suppose $d\bigl((x,y),(1-1)\bigr)<\delta<\frac12$. Observe that this implies both $|x-1|<\delta$ and $|y+1|<\delta$.

- $|4x+y-3|=|4(x-1)-(y+1)|<4|x-1|+|y+1|<5\delta\,$;
- $|1-x+y|>\bigl||y|-|1-x|\bigr|=|y|-|1-x|$ if $\delta$ is small enough. Note that, since $|y+1|<\delta$, $|y|>1-\delta$ and since $|1-x|<\delta $, $-|1-x|>-\delta$. Thus we obtain finally
  $$|1-x+y|>1-2\delta,\quad\text{and}\quad\biggl|\,\frac{x+4y}{1-x+y}-3\,\biggr|<\frac{5\delta}{1-2\delta}$$
  Given $\varepsilon>0$, we simply have to solve for $\delta$:

$$\frac{5\delta}{1-2\delta}<\varepsilon\iff\delta<\frac\varepsilon{5+2\varepsilon} $$
(strictly speaking, we should check that $\delta<\frac12$, but it is clear this condition is fulfilled if $\varepsilon$ is small enough).